# days between 2 dates dependent on ID

Tags: sql, between, days

I have ID & Order Date column; what I want to do is show for each ID what was the difference between the Next order date and current.

Table

| ID | Order Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/12/2020 |
| 2 | 15/09/2020 |
| 2 | 01/10/2020 |
| 3 | 31/12/2020 |
| 4 | 01/10/2020 |
| 4 | 03/10/2020 |
| 4 | 01/12/2020 |
| 5 | 31/01/2020 |

What Id Expect:

| ID | Order Date | Days between |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/12/2020 | n/a |
| 2 | 15/09/2020 | 77 days |
| 2 | 01/10/2020 | n/a |
| 3 | 31/12/2020 | n/a |
| 4 | 01/10/2020 | 2 days |
| 4 | 03/10/2020 | 59 days |
| 4 | 01/12/2020 | n/a |
| 5 | 31/01/2020 | 0 |

all help welcome... p.s. im failry new to SQL so only have a basic understanding

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

First, in SQL, you should just have a column with the number of days -- a number.  Don't convert the value to a string.  What you call `'N/A'` should be a `NULL` value.

To do what you want, use `lag()`.  It is something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (order_date -
        lag(order_date) over (partition by id order by order_date)
       ) as date_diff
from t;
```

Note that not all databases support `-` on dates.  The exact syntax for date operations usually varies depending on the database.

Answer (score 1):

The days between value of 77 seems wrong. See results below. This is thge same as the above solution, Only using datediff() instead.

```
create table T (ID int, OrderDate datetime)

insert into T (ID, OrderDate)
  values ( 1, cast('01/12/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 2, cast('15/09/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 2, cast('01/10/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 3, cast('31/12/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 4, cast('01/10/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 4, cast('03/10/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 4, cast('01/12/2020' as datetime) ),
         ( 5, cast('31/01/2020' as datetime) )

select  *, datediff(day, OrderDate, lag(orderdate) over(partition by ID order by ID, Orderdate desc)) as [Days Between]
from    T 
order by ID, OrderDate asc
```

| ID | Orderdate | Days Between |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 16 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 3 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 4 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 4 | 2020-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 59 |
| 4 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 5 | 2020-01-31 00:00:00.000 | NULL |

Comment: I think you should sanity check your logic - this is suggesting there are 16 days between the 15th of September 2020 and the 1st of December 2020 - 77 seems more correct to me

Comment: Actually, you are right - I missed that first/second row were diff IDs! *self-terminates*